# Непонятки с адаптивностью

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, адаптивность

Добрый день!

Растолкуйте пожалуйста, есть сайт, есть адаптивность с помощью медиа запросов, но фишка в том, что на некоторых мобилках не срабатывает правило нужное. Например, есть правило написанное для @media (max-width: 660px). Захожу с хуавея, у которого разрешение экрана 1920x1080, а в браузере 540 на что то там (это уже позже через сервисы пробил его). Так вот, правило не срабатывает, так как у него типа фуллхд, но при этом в браузере он мнет весь контент пытаясь уместить все в 540 по ширине. Как быть в таких случаях? я что то не понимаю)

Comment: В браузере выключите "Полная версия"

Comment: это же не решение проблемы

Comment: Это решение проблемы. В режиме "полная версия" браузер не обращает внимания на актуальную ширину экрана, никакие @media принципиально не работают.

Comment: ну я же делаю адаптивную версию, я же не смогу каждому пользователю говорить, чтобы он выключил полную версию

Comment: Есть правила пользования браузером. Вы еще можете захотеть, чтобы браузер запускал ракеты в космос. Но такой функции в нем нет. Также нет у браузеров возможности отображать @media в полной версии.

Comment: Полная версия для того и придумана, чтобы отключить адаптивность

Comment: Если дело в этом, то ладно) яж думал, что руки ни с тогоместа. спасибо за !совет